# How to get column name from table from 2 rows of same table having same value?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005

```
Id  BatchName      TblName           SubBatchName     Status
1   12032014    Tbl_12032014_raw2_1  raw2           Complete    
2   12032014    Tbl_12032014_raw2_2  raw2           Complete    
3   12182014    Tbl_12182014_raw3_1  raw3           Complete        
4   12182014    Tbl_12182014_raw3_2  raw3           Complete        
5   12182014    Tbl_12182014_raw4_1  raw4           Complete        
6   12182014    Tbl_12182014_raw4_2  raw4           Complete        
7   12062014    Tbl_12062014_raw5_1  raw5           Complete    
8   12062014    Tbl_12062014_raw5_2  raw5           Complete
9   12062014    Tbl_12062014_raw5_3  raw5           InComplete
```

i want output like below

```
BatchName                                                                                 
--------------------
12032014  
12182014
```

If all rows of batchname are having status complete then and then only BatchName Get select

Thanks

Comment: Searching something about GROUP BY could be very useful here

Comment: `raw2_0` what is `0` here..

Comment: plz help me.... how to use group by here

Comment: sorry Rahul its like raw2 only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:-

```
SELECT BatchName, SubBatchName
FROM [Table]
WHERE Status = 'Complete' 
GROUP BY BatchName,SubBatchName
HAVING COUNT(SubBatchName) > 1
```

Comment: thanks buddy bt still it return 12082014 batchname and raw3 as subbatchname

Comment: @AsifMULLA - You should not keep on changing your questing frequently, just be sure what you want. Have updated the answer. Please verfiy.

Comment: i have lots rows in my table whose status may complte or may not

Comment: @AsifMULLA - I think you need only those rows which have more than 1 subbatchname, have updated the answer based on your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
select BatchName,SubBatchname from tablename where BatchName='12032014' and Status='Complete' group by BatchName,SubBatchName;
```

[Group By](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp)

Comment: this query also returns 12082014 batchName

Comment: if you only get records for 12032014 then use in where clause.